# Swifty json error when i run the app on my mobile devise after update Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, swifty-json

I have updated the Xcode to the latest version (7.3). and my mobile OS (9.3). I am using carthage and updated libraries also.

I could run my project in Xcode simulator without error. but when i try to run the project on my mobile devise it gives a JSON error.

Simulator version also 9.3

> Use of undeclared type 'JSON'

Simulator version also 9.3

I could not find a source to solve this problem. so please help me to solve this.

Comment: please check  public struct JSON in  "SwiftyJSON.swift"  file.

Comment: Have you tried "Resolve build failures" from https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage? I'm using CocoaPods and have no problems with SwiftyJSON in Xcode 7.3 and iOS 9.3 simulator/device.

Comment: @Tapani Yes i have tried but could not fixed yet